# SMS Gateway won't send sms

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do a simple select and send it via SMS Gateway but when I send the message that should run the function nothing happens. This is the function that i wrote. Sender should send "utakmice x" where the x is the number of the next x events that are sent from the database:

```php
function utakmice($broj) {
  $conn = connect();
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
    $smsporuka = "Ne moze se uspostaviti konekcija sa bazom, pokusajte kasnije.";
  } else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM utakmica ORDER BY datum LIMIT = $broj;";
    $rezultat = mysql_query($query);
    if($rezultat) {
      if(mysql_num_rows($rezultat) !== 0) {
        $smsporuka="";
        while($red = mysql_fetch_array($rezultat)) {
          $smsporuka .= "(".$red["id_tekma"]." ".$red["protivnik"].",".$red["cena"]."RSD datum: ".$red["datum"].")";
        }
      } else {
        $smsporuka = "Nema selektovanih utakmica!";
      }
    }
  }
  disconnect($conn);
  sendResponse($smsporuka);
}
```

Here is the code before the functions, function info works as it's supposed to work:

```php
function sendResponse($t) {
  $reply = rawurlencode($t);
  header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
  header("text: ".$reply);
}

if(empty($text) || strlen($text) == 0 || $text == "") {
  $smsporuka = "Poslali ste sms poruku u losem formatu, za vise informacija posaljite INFO.";
  sendResponse($smsporuka);
} else {
  $text = str_replace(";", "", $text);
  $explodeovanText = explode(' ',trim($text));
  $komanda = strtolower($explodeovanText[0]);
  switch ($komanda) {
    case "info":
      info();
      break;
    case "utakmice":
      utakmice($explodeovanText[1]);
      break;
    case "dodaj":
      dodaj($explodeovanText[1], $explodeovanText[2]);
      break;
    case "rezervisi":
      rezervisi($explodeovanText[1], $explodeovanText[2]);
      break;
    case "otkazi":
      otkazi($explodeovanText[2]);
      break;
  }
}

function info() {
  $smsporuka = "Posaljite UTAKMICA da bi ste videli narednih 5 protivnika i datume utakmica. Posaljite REZ_x_y, gde je x id utakmice, a y broj mesta koje rezervisete.";
  sendResponse($smsporuka);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! mysql functions were supposed to be mysqli and the query was not correct. Here is the solution. Also in the beginning I set the default parameter to be 5.

```
function utakmice($broj = 5) {
  $smsporuka = "";
  $conn = connect();
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
     $smsporuka = "Ne moze se uspostaviti konekcija sa bazom, pokusajte kasnije.";
  } else {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM utakmica ORDER BY datum LIMIT $broj;";
      $rezultat = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
      if($rezultat) {
        if(mysqli_num_rows($rezultat) !== 0) {
           $smsporuka="";
           while($red = mysqli_fetch_array($rezultat)) {
             $smsporuka .= "(".$red["id_tekma"]." ".$red["protivnik"].",".$red["cena"]."RSD datum: ".$red["datum"].")";
           }
        } 
        else {
    $smsporuka = "Nema selektovanih utakmica!";
        }
      }
   }
disconnect($conn);
sendResponse($smsporuka);
}
```